# Asterisk 1.8 Database and Digium GUI syncronization

Tags: mysql, linux, user-interface, asterisk, pbx

I am using ODBC to make connection between MySQL and Asterisk and its working well.
But if administrator crate new extension by editing users.conf of Asterisk GUI then that user information is not stored in MySQL database. Do you got any idea to synchronize them all ?

Your advice will be highly appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: are you using [Asterisk RealTime](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime)? if so then Asterisk will fetch users list directly from database. so just add new users into database instead of conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not compleatly sure, but maybe that GUI store info in  FILES,not database?

Comment: Yes Digium GUI define users in file called "users.conf" not in database.

Comment: so what u want? you have rewrite/write your own to store to mysql. or rewrite your part to store in files.

Comment: I want to do this
1) Create User from Digium GUI.
2) That user can be also found in MySQL Database.
3) Delete User from Digium GUI
4) That user is also deleted from MySQL Database.

Comment: Sorry, that is not posible.Asterisk have no internal mechanism of store config in database. GUI use internal "save dialplan" command,which save to files. You have rewrite GUI acordinly. But create gui from sratch will be less complex. It is like " i have a car and a boat. i want when i drive car i able run over river on it"

Comment: Yes i think you are right. I have imagine my own ways to update database. Soon i will post it on an article.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible some command to create a connection between asterisk1.8 to mysql(odbc):
if you reply me then i show you the command and also pbx connection

Comment: Bhai jaan ab ye wekth agya hai k app hum ko sekhay gaay :p